# variadic struct specification

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I define a variadic struct like so

```
template <class T, class... TRest>
struct Opa
{
    Opa()
    {
        std::cout << "Mutiple-arguments template";
    }
};
```

and want to specialize it for the case with 1 argument only as follows

```
template <>
struct Opa<class T>
{
    Opa()
    {
        std::cout << "One-argument template";
    }
};
```

but compiler just ignores this second struct, and the output from

```
Opa<int> opa;
Opa<int, int> opa_opa;
```

is `Mutiple-arguments template, Mutiple-arguments template`.

Specifying one-argument template in different ways, e.g.

```
template <class T>
struct Opa
{...}
```

resulted in a compilation error.
I realize that my question is quite simple, but googling didn't help.
So please don't throw rotten tomatoes at me, and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Where is your variadic template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax for the single-argument specialisation is wrong. You're probably fully specialising it for an on-the-spot declared `class T`. You wanted this:

```
template <class T>
struct Opa<T>
{
    Opa()
    {
        std::cout << "One-argument template";
    }
};
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/96ZOHm)

Partial specialisations are declared by listing the *parameters* of the partial specialisation in the angle brackets after `template` (in your case, a single type parameter, `class T`), and listing the *arguments* for the primary template in the angle brackets after the primary template's name (in your case, a single type argument, `T`).